# Can Windows Vista be installed on Mac OS X 10.6.6?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I heard that as of Mac OS X 10.6.6, [Apple removed wording about installing Vista via Boot Camp](http://www.macnn.com/articles/11/01/17/drops.xp.vista.references.requires.download/), suggesting that they are no longer supporting it.

If I have Mac OS X 10.6.6 installed, can I still install a full version of Vista on it?

Comment: As I know Apple won't support windows XP and vista in 10.6.6 bootcamp but you can install them if you want. it's just like Microsoft that didn't support windows 98 any more but you can still install this version if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to Apple's [Snow Leopard Specs](http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html).

> **Boot Camp:**
>
>   requires Windows XP with
>   Service Pack 2 or Windows Vista (sold
>   separately).

Also, you can install Windows 7 if you update Boot Camp. Info [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986).

Comment: Windows 7 is compatible as well.

Comment: @mummey updated.

Comment: The only issue I could possibly foresee is if Apple removes WinXP or Vista support from it's Boot Camp drivers. Otherwise, should be free and clear.